# How to call onTouch() method

Tags: java, android

I would like please to call `onTouch()` method which is in different class than the method `onOptionsItemSelected()` I want to call from, here's the code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             float downx = 0, downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0;
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              downx = event.getX();
              downy = event.getY();
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              upx = event.getX();
              upy = event.getY();
              mCanvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, mPaint);
              invalidate();
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
              break;
            default:
              break;
            }
            return true;
          }
```

The method that I wanted to call `onTouch()` from:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.LINE_ID:
            //i want to call it here            
            return true;
```

`onOptionsItemSelected()` is in `MainClass` but `onTouch()` is in a subclass of `MainClass`.

How i can do that? how i can call drawLine()?

UPDATE:

I tried :

```
View v = null; MotionEvent event = null;
            MyView sub_class = new MyView(getBaseContext());
            sub_class.onTouch(v, event);
```

but it's crashed!
Any Help please! I think this is very easy for some ppl.. They don't care :(

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be calling `onTouch()` at all. This is something that the Android system generates when there's a touch event, not something that you should be calling manually. If nothing else, how would you work out what `MotionEvent` to pass it?

What you need to do is to call whatever method your `onTouch()` method invokes when a touch event comes in. Refactor your `onTouch()` so that it calls a method, with appropriate parameters, that behaves appropriately when a touch event occurs; and then have your `onOptionsItemSelected()` call that method too.

Comment: i have two touch listners, how i can trigger a specific one?

Comment: @New2Android This is exactly the point! You should look to see whatever it is that your `onTouch()` method does when a touch comes in; and then you should do that. You shouldn't trigger a touch listener at all. It gets triggered by the system.

Comment: how i can call drawline() then?

Comment: can you suggest please a solution?

Comment: @New2Android it's not really possible to suggest a good solution without seeing all your code and understanding what you're trying to achieve. But I really think your best strategy is to find some Android tutorials and work carefully through them, otherwise you're in danger of writing code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Though you should not call Android View's internal methods which are invoked by the OS itself. 
However, you can still do this by simply creating an instance on the sub-class and invoking the onTouch method through this object. 
Check the code below:

```
SubClass sub_class = new SubClass();
sub_class.onTouch(v, event);
```

Comment: I have "event cannot be resolved to a variable" my code is:  MyView sub_class = new MyView(getBaseContext());
   sub_class.onTouch(v, event);

Comment: i have that error on sub_class.onTouch(v, event); how to solve it?

Comment: Did you set any action in the event which you passed?
I see that 3rd line looks for action: "event.getAction()", which is the reason for that error.

Comment: Accept the answer if it is correct to call the method!

Comment: i will accept it for sure, help me with event error please

Comment: I have tested this yesterday, but it's crashed! can you move please this discussion to a chat, i don't have enough points